# NSFetchedResultsController, modifying the NSFetchRequest?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I have setup a `NSFetchRequestController` that uses three pre-computer objectIDs as the `NSPredicate` in its `initWithFetchRequest:` parameter.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [[self managedDocument] managedObjectContext];
[self setFetchedResultsController:[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]initWithFetchRequest:fRequest
                                                                     managedObjectContext:moc
                                                                       sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                cacheName:nil]];
```

My question is once I have setup my `NSFetchedResultsController` is there a way to modify the `NSFetchRequest` used by the controller as new data becomes available in the database. I noticed that the request is readOnly so thats out, are there any other options available to me?

## EDIT:

I was thinking I would need to change the whole request, but maybe I could just set a new NSPredicate using the existing NSFetchedResultsController and existing NSFetchRequest, would that be the way to do this?

Comment: as far as i know, there is not a method for mutating the NSFetchedResultsController. you have to create new controller.

Comment: I just tried what I alluded too in the EDIT: and it does seem to allow for the NSFetchReqest to be modified to include a new NSPredicate before sending the performFetch message to the NSFetchedResultsController to display the update.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/

**Modifying the Fetch Request**

You cannot simply change the fetch request to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you must:

If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).

Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch request.

Change the fetch request. (Modify the predicate)

Invoke performFetch:.